# Appmaker with BigQuery (Read/Write/Update/Delete)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-app-maker

I am working on a project where I am using Google App-maker as Front-end and BigQuery as backend.

I understand currently there are no App-maker models which are fully integrated with BigQuery, hence probably we will have to use some server side scripts to read/insert/update/delete.

I was able to read the data from BigQuery via App-maker, however, I am looking for help with insert/update/delete.

I would like to know, if anyone has implemented this functionality and if yes, can you please help share the code snippet or example.

Thank you

Comment: I wonder if this is what you are looking for: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. 

I am looking to write these inserts/update/deletes via App-maker and I am looking to find a way to write script in App-maker so it can update Bigquery. (basically, script for CRUD in app-maker)

Comment: Can you please let me know how did you read data from BigQuery via App Maker? I think that you can actually use the Apps Script OAuth Client Library (https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) with App Maker and then you should be able to use the BigQuery Rest APIs (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) to read or write data via OAuth 2.0 or even using a Service Account.

Comment: I am using Advance Services in appmaker and calling the BigQuery API to read the data by writing a script.

Comment: I am using Advance Services in appmaker and calling the BigQuery API to read the data by calling a script.
However, I am struggling to write a script to insert/update/delete and I am looking for help to write them.

Comment: Take a look at this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287957