# How can I link my spread sheets to App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm a new user of App Maker and I've just started coding with Google App Scripts, so basically I don't know so many things about the subject, and today I'm working on a app that already exists at Google Sheets, and I have to  recreate it using App Maker. The only problem is that I have all my data and scripts on Google Sheets and my boss asked to not import data but to link the App Maker with spread sheet. For example I have a search form and when I click the submit button I get the values that the user entered in the form and place them into the existing search form in Google Sheets and run the script in Google Sheet, and then get the search results from Sheets and display them in App Maker, please any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access Google Sheets files using [Spreadsheet Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). This API provides full CRUD access to Spreadsheet files:

```javascript
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
...
```

Full sample code lives here:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/spreadsheet/

In answer to this question you can find high level steps to build UI for some 3rd party services with App Maker: [Google App Maker how to create Data Source from Google Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287957)