# Error when fetching data from spreadsheet

Tags: google-app-maker

After eagerly waiting for appmaker its finally here! I immediately started diving into it and i love it.
I want to make a basic app to track the status of our chromebooks from a spreadsheet, which i think appmaker is quite a good option for.

Well, i followed the database connection screen and got everything hooked up, but when i try to load it in via a widget is gives me a error when i run the app
I get the following error:

E

Fri Jun 15 12:40:08 GMT+200 2018

The function queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was explicitly returned. Error: The function queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was explicitly returned.
E

Fri Jun 15 12:40:08 GMT+200 2018

Executing query for datasource InventorySheet: (Error) : The function queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was explicitly returned.
E

Fri Jun 15 12:40:08 GMT+200 2018

Executing query for datasource InventorySheet failed.

How do we fix this?

Greetings,
Luuk

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646795/